# text output with color

Tags: python, html

Fellow programmers, 
I am running a Monte Carlo type simulation in python that generates long strings of 0,1, and 2's and I'm trying to output them in a text or html file for further analysis.

I'd like to print these strings in an external file, and use different colors for the different digits. 
Say, 0 = red, 1 = green, and 2 = two.

My knowledge of Python, and html is somehow limited. Any "pointers"(sorry for unintentional pun) and sample bits of code will be very welcome.

Comment: question contains insufficient specific information to be answered.

Comment: your strings are going to be phenomenally long with an indicator between each digit setting their color - I'm not aware of any way to do this with css - maybe somebody on webmasters can help?

Comment: More specs. I have a numerical simulation where 3 types of events may occur as time goes by. For each output I have assigned a letter, say 0, 1 and 2 and I'd like to register these events only, instead of recording the entire simulation. My idea was to code a module that would spit off these events in a html file using different colors for each event, with the purpose of visualizing the different patterns being formed. Ideally these strings would be dealt with statiscally.

Comment: would u mind giving a comment on my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

just write to a file like this and open it in a webbrowser:

```
def write_red(f, str_):
    f.write('<p style="color:#ff0000">%s</p>' % str_)

def write_blue(f, str_):
    # ...

f = open('out.html', 'w')
f.write('<html>')

write_red(f, thing_i_want_to_be_red_in_output)

f.write('</html>')
f.close()
```

**Update**: To make this answer complete, with the use of css, the output file can be much smaller.

```
style = """<style type='text/css'>
html {
  font-family: Courier;
}
r {
  color: #ff0000;
}
g {
  color: #00ff00;
}
b {
  color: #0000ff;
}
</style>"""

RED = 'r'
GREEN = 'g'
BLUE = 'b'

def write_html(f, type, str_):
    f.write('<%(type)s>%(str)s</%(type)s>' % {
            'type': type, 'str': str_ } )

f = open('out.html', 'w')
f.write('<html>')
f.write(style)

write_html(f, RED, 'My name is so foo..\n')
write_html(f, BLUE, '102838183820038.028391')

f.write('</html>')
```

Comment: just an fyi: the OP says `generates long strings of 0,1, and 2's` imagine this page with 100 numbers, imagine it with 1000 numbers?

Comment: Formatted text is always bigger than normal text. But there is a more efficient way using css. I'm going to add this.